# Console log an interface without some object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, logging, console

Do you know how can I console log the interface example **without the m and n**?
Below the two interface is in one file.

```
export interface example {
  readonly a: string;
  readonly b: F | undefined;
  readonly c: G | undefined;
  readonly d?: boolean;
  readonly e: H | undefined;
}
export interface F {
  readonly i: string;
  readonly j: q;
  readonly k: string | undefined;
  readonly l: r;
  readonly m: s | undefined;
  readonly n: t | undefined;
  readonly o: y | undefined;
  readonly p: v[] | undefined;
}
```

Below is in another file

```
import { example } from 'src/modules/ex';

exampleInfo: example | undefined;
console.log( exampleInfo.a + exampleInfo.b.i + exampleInfo.b.j + exampleInfo.b.k + exampleInfo.b.l + exampleInfo.b.o + exampleInfo.b.p + exampleInfo.c + exampleInfo.d+ exampleInfo.e)
```

Currently the console log is super long and easy to make mistake. Also I want to include the key(a,b,c,o,p...etc).not just the value.
If I simply type

```
console.log(exampleInfo);
```

I can get the result I want (with all key and value pair). However, it's included the m&n that I don't want.

I've also tried to destruct it.

```
const {m,n, ...otherChar} = exampleInfo;
```

But it gives me error:

```
"Property 'm' does not exist on type 'example | undefined'.
```

Or

```
const {F.m,F.n, ... otherChar} = exampleInfo;
```

But still error:

```
 "Property 'F' does not exist on type 'example | undefined'.
```

Also tried this:

```
const {m,n, …otherChar} = exampleInfo.b;
```

Error changed to:

```
Property 'm' does not exist on type 'F | undefined'.
```

How should I destruct it? or is there any other way to log them??

Answer (score 1):

Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(example))`

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't see the requirement clearly. Not sure this is optimal solution, but hope it helps.

```
let b = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(example.b).filter(x => x[0] != 'm' && x[0] != 'n'));
const result = {...example};
result.b = b;
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Hi, it is not exclude the m & n. I want to print out everything in example without m & n

Comment: Edited answer, please check

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>): [string, unknown][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'F | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string, any][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'F | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.ts(2769)